# algoritmo que acha os números primos em um intervalo

Tags: c

to tendo problemas com esse código, já vi em vários lugares como corrigir, mas eu realmente não consigo achar o erro, ele imprimi valores os valores do intervalo inteiro, nao apenas primos.

// O programara informara ao usuario os numeros primos em um intervalo definido

```
int main () 
{
    int a,b,n,cont,primo;

    printf("Digite o infimo e o supremo de um intervalo, separados por espaço:\n");
    scanf("%i %i", &a, &b);

    if (a > b)
        printf("erro\n");
    else
        for (cont = a; cont <= b; cont++){
            primo = 0;
            for(n = 1; n <= cont; n++){
                if(cont % n == 0);
                    primo++;
            }
            if(primo == 2)
                printf("%d\n", cont);    
        }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Erro de digitação:

```c
                if(cont % n == 0);
                    primo++;
```

O problema está no ponto-e-vírgula no final da linha do `if` que não deveria estar ali.

Ah, e como uma observação, a variável `primo` na verdade deveria se chamar `divisores_encontrados` ou coisa parecida, vez que ela conta quantos divisores `cont` tem, e não quantos números primos foram encontrados.

Comment: Caraca, deu certinho, muito obrigado. Só mais uma duvida, em termos de sintaxe , como o ; é interpretado, pq ocorre essa diferença. 
Novamente agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: @VíctorVianna O `;` é interpretado como uma instrução vazia que não faz nada, o que significa que o `primo++;` na verdade está depois do `if`, e não dentro dele.

Comment: @VíctorVianna Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.